# Using JS or Jquery to Replace All Instances of a nested key within a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div.  I want to replace all instances of [1234] for example with, let's say [5678], but only within the #groovy DIV, not within the entire doc.

I have tried:

```
  jQuery("#groovy").html().replace(/stuff\[1234\]/g,"stuff[5678]");
```

And I am not having any luck with that.

```
<div id="groovy">
<h1>Some Stuff</h1>
<input name="stuff[1234][morestuff][otherstuff]">
<p>Things</p>
<input name="stuff[1234][goodstuff][betterstuff]">
<div class="telly">
<input name="stuff[1234][badstuff][decentstuff]">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not having any luck"?

Comment: `.replace()` does not alter the original String, it returns a new String. You need to assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#groovy input[name*='[1234]']").each(function(){
  var item = $(this);
  item.attr('name', item.attr('name').replace('[1234]', '[5678]'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="groovy">
<h1>Some Stuff</h1>
<input name="stuff[1234][morestuff][otherstuff]">
<p>Things</p>
<input name="stuff[1234][goodstuff][betterstuff]">
<div class="telly">
<input name="stuff[1234][badstuff][decentstuff]">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to both access the contents of `#groovy` (as you are doing), and then apply the updated contents back to that element:

```js
/* Obtain html content of groovy */
const originalHtml = jQuery("#groovy").html();

/* Update html as required */
const updatedHtml = originalHtml.replace(/stuff\[1234\]/g, "stuff[5678]");

/* Apply updated html back to groovy element */
jQuery("#groovy").html(updatedHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="groovy">
  <h1>Some Stuff</h1>
  <input name="stuff[1234][morestuff][otherstuff]">
  <p>Things</p>
  <input name="stuff[1234][goodstuff][betterstuff]">
  <div class="telly">
    <input name="stuff[1234][badstuff][decentstuff]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will *get* the contents of the HTML tag, return them, then replace the string value. The problem is that you are not setting the contents when you are done.

```
jQuery("#groovy").html().replace(/stuff\[1234\]/g,"stuff[5678]");
```

Try something like this:

```
const elem = jQuery("#groovy");
elem.html(elem.html().replace(/stuff\[1234\]/g,"stuff[5678]"));
```

Comment: One follow up if I may @Jason.  I need the 1234 to be a variable and am having a heck of a time making that happen for some reason.  elem.html(elem.html().replace(/stuff\["+currentid+"\]/g,"stuff["5678"]")); doesn't work and in my code editor, it isn't correct. Any ID how to format that right?  All else appears to be working well. :)